# how to send through ServletOutputStream characters in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, internationalization

My servlet code looks like that:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.println(...MY-UTF-8 CODE...);
```

...

then I get the error:

```
java.io.CharConversionException: Not an ISO 8859-1 character: ש
 javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream.print(ServletOutputStream.java:89)
 javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream.println(ServletOutputStream.java:242)
 rtm.servlets.CampaignLogicServlet.doPost(CampaignLogicServlet.java:68)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

How can I switch the charset of Servlet's outputstream ???

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I think you want to use [getWriter()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) instead. That will accept a string and encode it, whereas the output stream is for handling *binary* data.

From the doc:

> Returns a PrintWriter object that can
>   send character text to the client. The
>   character encoding used is the one
>   specified in the charset= property of
>   the setContentType(java.lang.String) 
>   method, which must be called before
>   calling this method for the charset to
>   take effect.
>
> Either this method or
>   getOutputStream() may be called to
>   write the body, not both.

Here's the change of the code:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(...MY-UTF-8 CODE...);
```

Answer (score 13):

This also works:

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write("MY-UTF-8 CODE".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: working for me too, but why does it work with `write` but not with `print`/`println`?

Comment: @moeTi This is weird for me as well. Any explanations?

Comment: @moeTi The `print` function will encode the data in the format that is specified in the characterEncoding of the `response` object. If you didn't set a characterEncoding header, the default is to use ISO-8859-1 https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Response.java#L902

Answer (score 4):

The same case happen to me before and i tried to add-on one line on top of the PrintWriter and it is work.

***response.setContentType("text/html; charset=GBK");*** 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

Answer (score 2):

In the case where you have to Request Dispatcher from a doFilter to @WebServlet("/anywebpage") which should only contain the PrintWriter out =  response.getWriter();

```
        String erpg = "anywebpage";
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(erpg);
        rd.include(request, response);
```

You should NOT require to declare the following line:
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Instead, make sure to include the following before the PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  instruction:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void output(String jsonStr, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8;");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(jsonStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// HTML Output code list
StringBuffer select_code = new StringBuffer();
List<con_element> ccc = codeService.code_select(code);

for(int i=0;i<ccc.size();i++){
    select_code.append("<option value='" + ccc.get(i).getCce_num() + "'>" + ccc.get(i).getCce_hname() + "</option>" );
}

response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().print( select_code );
```